# how to use the compiling time as automatic versioning-info?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

is there any constant or #pragma to get the time and date, when the programm was beeing compiled to get a kind of an automatic version-info ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__DATE__` and `__TIME__` are predefined macros that will expand to the current date, and time, respectively.

Comment: thank you, works fine. further information, if anybody reads this later: it returns a c-string, so use %s, %@ doesnt work as it is no object.